# Insert values in a table based on entries of other table in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have two tables in AWS Redshift and need to insert some values into one table based on the entries of the other. I want to know if it is  possible to accomplish the task using a AWS GLUE job, if so, will that be a good idea? Or should I use the query-editor/sqlworkbench in Redshift to accomplish the task.

- Table 1 has the following schema:

```
Person(id,firstName,Lastname)
```

- Table 2 has the following schema

```
Selection(perId,check)
```

- If the concatenation of `firstName` and `lastName` of Person table lies in `['fullName1', 'fullName2',..]` then then  insert 1 in the selection table otherwise  0 with the respective id of person.

**Example**

- the list values are: `['JohnLuie' , 'FranklinWatson']`

  **person table**

```
    Id   |        Firstname           |   lastName   
    04   |           John             |           Luie
    09   |           Ben              |         Johnson
```

Initially the Selection Table is empty.  So after checking with the condition on person table That is if

- `(Person.firstName+ Person.lastName) in ['JohnLuie' , 'FranklinWatson]` then insert 1 or 0 in Selection.check with person.id in Selection.perId

So after performing the task the Selection table will look like:

**Selection**

```
    PerId      |     check
     04        |        1
     09        |        0
```

I want to know if I can perform the following task by running aws-glue job. Both the tables are in redshift.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide an example... That is, please provide some samples of what is in one table and what you would like to appear in the other table. It is possible that this can be performed via a simple SQL statement, but without knowing the details, it is not possible to say!

Comment: I have edited the question and added an example.

Comment: Where does the list (`['JohnLuie' , 'FranklinWatson]`) come from?

Comment: Those are some predefined values. The list values aren't coming from any table.

Comment: It is definitely possible to do this with Glue, but this makes things much more complicated than needed. It really is not a good use case for Glue. When the data is already available in Redshift, just use SQL directly as suggested by John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do it in an SQL query, something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO Selection
(
    SELECT
      Id,
      CASE WHEN firstName || lastName IN ['JohnLuie' , 'FranklinWatson] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM person
)
```